# Node Extracting zip file async using callbacks or events?

Tags: node.js, events, asynchronous, callback, eventemitter

I have to write a module whose **task is to extract a zip file given two parameters** (`zip file's path`, `directory where to extract's path`) which should expose a **method to perform the task and then trigger another task if operation was successful**.

My main concern is : **should i use a callback design pattern or an observable event emitter one** ?

Basically, on I am wondering if I should expose an object which extends events' module that would be observable on something like `extraction-complete` event Or if i should i use a `callback(err, 'ok')` if it's successful.

What would be the clever approach between the two patterns ?

My goal is to unzip a file then browse the content of the extracted archive and write some information in a database from the extracted folders. The folder is a zip file consisting of folders with images in it and does have around 600 entries

Comment: Consider using promises.

Comment: I think both approaches are valid... also the promises approach is a valid approach... it just depends on your `design patterns`. Take a look to this list
https://blog.risingstack.com/fundamental-node-js-design-patterns/... just be consistent with the rest of your code and you should be good.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this command to install unzip first:

```
npm install unzip
```

then use the below code:

```
var unzip = require('unzip');

var stream = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/file.zip');
stream.pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: '/dest' })
    .on('close', function () {
        // Your callback code will go here...
    })
);
```

Comment: I am getting error after installing unzip module. error gets removed after uninstalling unzip module. Error looks like: c:\projects\electron\vendor\node\src\async-wrap.cc:357: Assertion `env->async_hooks_init_function().IsEmpty()' failed.